# How do I match? Regex: Match the string between ;string; excluding ;"string";

Tags: regex

I have a file which has multiple rows like below:

```
"47058";"post";keyword1;"Why is x bad?";"https://example.com/why-is-x-bad/"
"47059";"post";keyword2;"Why is y bad?";"https://example.com/why-is-y-bad/"
```

I want a regex that only matches keyword1 and keyword2, basically any string inside `;;` but excluding `;"";`

Goal: Add `""` around keyword1 and keyword2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want all matches where the keyword is just a set of letters surrounded by semi-colons (;) not surrounded by inverted commas(") followed by semi-colons.

Assuming the keyword only contains letters and nothing else.

You can use regex of `;[a-zA-Z]+;`

Tested on https://www.regextester.com/

[image]